# How to get a paired, connected Bluetooth headset to be recognized as an audio device?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

This happens on an Asus ROG G551JW computer. I got a Samsung Level U headset. I can get it paired via Bluetooth, but it's not recognized as a sound device: it doesn't appear in sound device lists, I can't control its volume nor make the system output the sound via the headset.

Relevant System Information:

- Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
- **Intel Bluetooth Driver version 19**: Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R) driver version 19.x.x.x
- Notification center -> Connect  displays Samsung Level U as Paired, but when attempting to Connect to it, it displays "Couldn't Connect".

  [image: Connect Pane]
  [image: Paired but Can't Connect]
- Power-cycling the headset changes its state to (presumably) connected, and the "Disconnect" button appears. But still: there are no audio devices available.

  [image: Connected]
- The device doesn't appear as an audio device:

  [image: No Samsung Level U :(]

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Make sure your Intel Wireless Bluetooth driver is at least of version 20.90, and enable all Bluetooth services for your headset device.

## Enable the needed Bluetooth Services on the Device

The device doesn't appear as an audio device in spite of being connected, because its audio-related services are not enabled. Navigate in Explorer to `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers`, right-click on the headset device, and select "Properties":

[image: Headset Properties]

In the device properties, the Bluetooth services related to audio are likely to be unchecked:

[image: Bluetooth Services for the headset]

Check all the services, and click "OK".

[image: Enabled Services]

There are two possible outcomes now:

1. The services will be enabled and the device will be recognized as a sound device.
2. "**The Supplied User Buffer is Invalid**" error dialog box will appear, once per each device.

## Fixing the Supplied User Buffer is Invalid error: Bluetooth Radio (host) Driver Update

If you get the error, the typical cause is an outdated Bluetooth radio hardware driver. As of 12/2018, the Intel driver version 19 is seemingly too old to reliably operate with the newest Windows Bluetooth stack.

The newest drivers for Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R) must be downloaded and installed from [Intel's site]. I chose the newest driver at this time: version [20.90](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28267/Intel-Wireless-Bluetooth-Software-for-Windows-10).

[image: Updated Intel Wireless Bluetooth Driver]

After installing the driver, power cycle the headset, ensure that it shows connected in the notification center's "Connect" pane, and re-enable the services as described above. After clicking "OK" to re-enable the services, the headset will become available for use as an audio output.

[image: Connect Pane]
[image: Connected]
[image: We have the headset for audio output!]